# How do I find multiple values, store them, and then manipulate them in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, find, vlookup

I am currently using VBA in excel on Financial Data.

Essentially what I want to do is find a value in column D "Automotive" and then find the corresponding value in Column G, for all occurrences of "Automotive".

Once I have all of the values (and there are many), I will then find "Automotive" and corresponding value in Column H. All of the values I will find I want to then perform a SUMPRODUCT on them.

So it will look something like this

```
Automotive       9.121..........................4.6 

X

Y 

Automotive       4.8............................2.2 

Z

B
```

I will store 9.121,4.8 in an Array (say Auto) and 4.6,2.2 in another.

Then the program will execute a sumproduct on all of the different values

```
(9.121 x 4.6) +

(4.6 x 2.2) +
...... etc.
```

Comment: Hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Which *specific* part of this is giving you problems?

Comment: Basically the issue I am having is writing a script that will locate Automotive, and then the corresponding value and appending it to a vector which I can then use to multiple against the corresponding value in another vector

Answer (score 0):

With questions like this it is usually best to disclose what you are planning to do with the result. The best plan of attack is often determined by where and how the result will be used.

I'm going to assume that a VBA function that will return a **double** that is the result you are looking for will be sufficient. Here are a few examples.

```
Function byProductAutomotiveA(rngA As Range, crt As String, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range)
    Dim frmla As String

    'like =SUMPRODUCT((B2:B10="Automotive")*(D2:D10)*(G2:G10))
    frmla = "=SUMPRODUCT((" & rngA.Address(external:=True) & "=""" & crt & """)*" & _
                        "(" & rng1.Address(external:=True) & ")*" & _
                        "(" & rng2.Address(external:=True) & "))"
                        'D2:D10)*(G2:G10))
    'Debug.Print frmla
    byProductAutomotiveA = Application.Evaluate(frmla)

End Function

Function byProductAutomotiveB(rngA As Range, crt As String, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, rslt As Double

    For Each rng In rngA
        If LCase(rng.Value2) = "automotive" Then
            rslt = rslt + (rng.Offset(0, rng1.Column - rng.Column).Value2 * rng.Offset(0, rng2.Column - rng.Column).Value2)
        End If
    Next rng

    byProductAutomotiveB = rslt

End Function

Sub byProductAutomotive()
    Dim rw As Long, rslt As Double

    With Worksheets("Automotive")
        For rw = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
            If LCase(.Cells(rw, 4).Value2) = "automotive" Then
                rslt = rslt + (.Cells(rw, 7).Value2 * .Cells(rw, 8).Value2)
            End If
        Next rw
        .Cells(13, 10) = rslt
    End With

End Sub
```

The following specifically discards hidden rows.

```
Function byProductAutomotiveBH(rngA As Range, crt As String, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, rslt As Double

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each rng In rngA
        If LCase(rng.Value2) = LCase(crt) And Not rngA.Parent.Rows(rng.Row).Hidden Then
            rslt = rslt + (rng.Offset(0, rng1.Column - rng.Column).Value2 * rng.Offset(0, rng2.Column - rng.Column).Value2)
        End If
    Next rng

    byProductAutomotiveBH = rslt

End Function
```

The functions can also be used to retrieve a result back to var in another sub. Be careful to get any [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) correct.

[image: VBA SUMPRODUCT]

Comment: Eventually I plan on using the data I find to create a bubble chart. I'll take values from several different search (Automotive, Industry,.....etc etc.) and make a chart

Comment: Thanks! They work perfect. The only thing that isn't working is the filtering option. I have used this code

 ActiveSheet.Range("A5").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:=">=0", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=2000"

To filter the data that the macro searches through but it doesn't affect the search. The result is still coming up the same despite the fact that I have attempted to filter.

I assume this is because Excel hides the cells and the macro will still pick them up when it looks through. Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: I've added filtered/hidden row criteria above.

Answer (score 0):

You probably already know that this does not have to be done in VBA. Excel can handle the analysis through its functions. However, if you were to write a script to first get the products and then get a grand total, there are several ways to do it. Here's one.

**Loop through the ranges, and keep a running sum.**

First, assume you have references to the Worksheet. We'll call it Sht here. Also, this example uses a *for each* loop, but a *for* loop is probably better (requires you to count the rows in the first column).

```
Sub AutoProdSum()

    Dim AutoR as Excel.Range
    Dim ColG as Excel.Range
    Dim ColH as Excel.Range

    Set AutoR = Sht.Range("$D:$D")
    Set ColG = Sht.Range("$G:$G")
    Set ColH = Sht.Range("$H:$H")

    Dim ThisAuto as Excel.Range
    Dim Var as Variant
    Dim ThisG as Excel.Range
    Dim valG as Double
    Dim ThisH as Excel.Range
    Dim valH as Double
    Dim prod as Double
      prod = 0
    Dim total as Double
      total = 0

    For Each Var in AutoR
      Set ThisAuto = AutoR.Find("Automotive",SearchBy:=xlValues)
      If ThisAuto.Value = "Automotive" Then
        Set ThisG = ThisAuto.Offset(0,3)
        Set ThisH = ThisAuto.Offset(0,4)
        valG = ThisG.Value
        valH = ThisG.Value
        prod = valG * valH
        total = total + prod

      End If
    Next

    MsgBox "The grand total is " & total
    'Or you can insert the total into the spreadsheet.

End Sub
```